# Сделать ссылку вместо текста jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть в html документе таблица такого вида:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="col1">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col1">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col1">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Нужно вместо цифр выводить такую ссылку `<a href="index.php?id=1">1</a>` как такое можно реализовать? и вообще ли такое возможно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хватаем все `td.col1` элементы, пробегаем по каждому, вытягиваем значение и сетаем новое по темплейту `<a href="index.php?id={id}">{id}</a>`.

Что-то вроде:

```js
$("td.col1").each(function(el) {
  let value = $(this).html();
  $(this).html('<a href="index.php?id=' + value + '">' + value + '</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col1">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Почитать:

- [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо

Answer (score 0):

Пробегаем по элементам, берем их текст, добавляем текст в ссылку, вставляем ссылку как html обратно.

```js
$('td.col1').each(function() {
  var innerText = $( this ).text();
  $( this ).html('<a href="index.php?id=' + innerText + '">' + innerText +'</a>');  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="col1">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col1">2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="col1">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что надо